# Redirect console output in sed in background process don't give back hand

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I'm using sed to add the date at the beginning of every lines given by a command (which use vlc and never stops...).
I found this way on another stackexchange post and that works as expected.

```
command | sed "s/^/$(date +%Z-%Y-%m-%d-%T) /" &>> $LOGFILE &
```

Now I want to use that from a script file as a background process.
My problem is that the script never finish and stop on this line.

If I understand well sed never finish as long as command is running but anyway it should run in background and go to the next step?

If I remove the sed part the script ends up as expected.

I'm running GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on Centos 6.4

Comment: try `bash path-to-your-script`. What do you see?

Comment: I just tried `bash script` but it still doesn't give back hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command needs to print a new-line to cause the pipe to process it.

```
test1(){ echo "testing-one"; sleep 100; }
test2(){ echo -n "testing-two"; sleep 100; }

test1| sed "s/^/$(date -u +%Z-%Y-%m-%d-%T)/"
```

When the function (serving as command proxy) tested is `test1`, it does emit a newline. When used, a line is emitted immediately, even if the command itself has not finished (sleep 100).

When the function test2 is used (edit the third line), the line is not emitted till the whole command line is finished.

Comment: The only part of this answer that might need quoting is the `$(date ...)` bit. Except that `^` is a non-standard `zsh` special pattern char, and so it might matter in that shell, and in crazy old Thomas shells *(I think that's what they were called)* it was the pipe token. It's probably theoretically correct though. Else if the asker is writing to a pipe it will very likely buffer.

Comment: @mikeserv The question is tagged bash, the user explains what version of bash he is using. Really: Where do you get it is zsh?

Comment: I don't - and that's why I said the only part of this that for which quotes might actually serve a purpose is the one part you don't quote. I only noted that `^` might need quotes in some other shells which are not the askers'.

Comment: The command, as posted by the user, does not work. I made the absolutely least of editing to get it work, making it easier for the OP to understand what is going on. Accepting that the result of date is perfectly valid, correct and does not have any external input, it is perfectly valid to NOT quote it (in bash). Clear now?.

Comment: @BinaryZebra You're right this is not my working command (I did so many tries... I posted the wrong one). I've just edited my post.

Comment: @Qumo Understood. Answer also edited.

Comment: @Qumo - actually, thinking about it, it's probably not `sed` at all and is instead *command*, or if it is `sed` the newline thing will matter, but it is more likely that your *command* actually *does* emit newlines, and `sed` just buffers its output. Try `sed -u ...`. Also note that `sed "s/^/$(date)/"` will not give you a *new* `date` for every input line, but will insert the first and only `date` output at the head of every output line regardless of how long the pipeline continues to run.

Comment: *command* is what I meant. That's the reason for test1 and test2 to be used as *command* substitute. if you need a command that blocks till the whole output is done, do `test1|xxd`

Comment: @mikeserv No, `sed "s/^/$(date)/"` will not emit a new date for each line. Is that what the user need? If so, let him figure it out and ASK.

Comment: @mikeserv I've tried with `sed -u` but it has no effect. My command uses java from sun jdk (which use vlc through vlcj...). I've looked into the java man page but I haven't found any option that can "force" to append a trailing newline. And yes the desired behavior is to emit a new date for each line, and indeed it look it does not work this way.

Comment: @mikeserv @BinaryZebra I thought sed was the problem because without the sed part the command return well and my script ends up as expected `java com.myapp.MyClass  &>> $LOGFILE &`

Comment: @Qumo I am sure that we do not have the whole picture to judge correctly. But hey, All is well that end's well.

Comment: @BinaryZebra As you well noticed the redirection to add current date at the beginning of every logs line does not work. So I rewrited this with awk `java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass 2>&1 | awk '{print strftime("%D %T",systime())" "$0 }' >> logFile.log &`. Now I have an other problem that is that the script wich is calling this script never exits... I did a new post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220497/bash-script-started-from-java-that-start-subscript-does-not-exits. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Qumo Not having read your other post, what should be the trigger for this action. Time?, an user click?, without a trigger action, there is nothing to make call the script.