# Bash script (with a java command) does not exit (script 2)

Tags: bash, centos, java

I start a bash script (synchronously from java as glassfish user) which triggers another bash script:

Script 1 executed from java:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Start script2 as myUser on myUser desktop
echo myPassword | su -c "export DISPLAY=:0.0;xhost +localhost;script2.sh;" myUser &
echo "After subscript"
#---------------
#... other tasks
#---------------
echo "Before exit"
exit 0
```

Script 2 executed from script 1

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start java app with date added by awk at the beginning of every line
java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass 2>&1 | awk '{print strftime("%D %T",systime())" "$0 }' >> logFile.log &

# Start java app without date added by awk on logs
#java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass 2>&1 >> logFile.log &
```

My problem is that the script 1 never exits unless I kill the java process started in the script 2.
This problem **DOES NOT** occurs if I remove the awk part in the script 2 (if I use the commented java command line).

I'm running : - GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on Centos 6.4
              - java 1.6.45 X86_64 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: try removing the background operator `&` from end of `awk` command

Comment: Ok, so I tried with this command: `java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass 2>&1 | awk '{print strftime("%D %T",systime())" "$0 }' >> logFile.log` but it still hangs.

Comment: @Qumo Does this code:  `var="$(java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass 2>&1)"` for script 2 exit?

Comment: @Qumo Ok, lets clear the java part. Making this the only executable (not commented) line in script2: `var="$(java -version)"` makes it exit?

Comment: @BinaryZebra `var="$(java -version)"` makes it exit. But I thinks it is not representative because my java program never exists.

Comment: @Qumo That is what problem solving is. Finding what works and what don't. Ok. So we know a java command could exit. Does this command exit as well?: ` var="$(java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass )"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

As far as I've understood it was the way to put in background both processes in my script 2.
It looks that the **&** apply only to **awk** (that would explain why it works without the awk part).

With braces I can put in background both parts (java and awk):

Script 2 executed from script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start java app with date added by awk at the beginning of every line
{ java -cp .:./lib/* com.mypackage.MyClass 2>&1 | awk '{print strftime("%D %T",systime())" "$0 }'; } &>> logFile.log &
```

Thanks everyone!